# HTML/JSP Display custom repeating background image for a table

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm trying to practice with this template:

[image]

I use table to display these books but I don't know how to display this empty book shelf image as background:

[image]

I tried with td and tr, but no use; I also tried this:

```
#main-table{
margin: 0 auto;
width : 1000px; 
background-image: url('images/EmptyWoodenShelf.png');
}
```

and here is result:

[image]

So is there any way that make an background repeat after about 100px ??

UPDATE:
Here is my css when I set background image for tr:

```
#main-table{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width : 1000px; 
}
#main-table tr{
    background-image: url('images/EmptyWoodenShelf.png');
    background-position: 0px 100px;
}
.tableitem{
    background-image: url('images/BookCover.png');
    background-position:center; 
    width:156px; 
    height:232px;
    margin: 50px 15px;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: easiest solution might be to just make the background image 100px high with transparent background, with the shelve at the top.

Comment: Try `background-position: 100px 0px;`.. where the first value represents the horizontal position, and the second represents the vertical position.

Comment: why dont you try setting the background-image to the `<tr>` ?

Comment: @Quintile: I can't do that because I get data from database and don't know how many shelf to display :P

Comment: @Lal: I tried the your 1st solution but they still display continuously.

Comment: but if you know that each book is 100px high, you'd set the background to be the 100px high shelve image with the transparent background, and set it to just repeat, and every 100px, or each row of books would have it's own shelf, even if there were 50 rows of books.

Comment: could you please post your new updated css..it would be helpful if you could reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Comment: sr for long reply, i updated css code

Comment: it would be helpful if you could reproduce the issue in a fiddle..please..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build in blank pixels into your shelf graphic so that the entire height of the graphic is 100px.

Although I would recommend instead that you add the background image to the TR, and position it at the bottom.  That way you can use your graphic as is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example i use a paragraph and give image border as you wanted

```css
#borderimg2 { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ8Lk.png) 30 stretch; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ8Lk.png) 30 stretch; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ8Lk.png) 30 stretch;
}
```

```html
<p id="borderimg2">Here, the middle sections of the image are stretched to create the border.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
background-position: 100px 0px;
```

The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. The top left corner is 0 0. Units can be pixels (0px 0px) or any other CSS units. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. You can mix % and positions

See more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530720(v=vs.85).aspx)